# How to get the cursor to blink upon the completion the second line - Typewriting effect using CSS

Tags: html, css, effect

I am trying to implement the typewriting effect on two lines for a webpage (black background), where I am not able to execute a cursor blinking once the second sentence has been typed out.

I have put out the HTML and CSS code. Any help in rectifying where I've gone wrong will be helpful.

HTML:

```
      <div class="typewriter">
        <h1>Hi,</h1>
        <h2>This is <span style="color: orange">ABC.</span></h2></div>
```

CSS:

```
.typewriter h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'DM Mono', monospace;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 80px;
    border-right: .15em solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: .15em;
    width: 4ch;
    animation: typing 2.5s steps(4, end), blink-caret .75s step-end 4;
  }
.typewriter h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'DM Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
    width: 20ch;
    animation: typing2 2s steps(20, end), blink-caret 1s step-end;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
@keyframes typing {
    from { 
        width: 0 
    }
    to { 
      width: 3em;
    }
}
@keyframes typing2 {
    from { 
        width: 0 
    }
    to { 
      width: 20em;
    }
}
@keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to {
      border-color: transparent
    }
    50% {
      border-color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you describe you issue a little bit more?

Comment: I want the cursor to keep blinking at the end of the second line whereas it disappears before finishing the second line.

Comment: Check the first example here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp. It has the word infinite, maybe this helps?

Comment: The animation is repeated infinite times over here which isn't what I'm looking for actually. I'm just concerned about the blinking of the cursor. 
Here is a link that I've referred to: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/)

Comment: Thanks for helping out! The cursor disappears after writing ABC. I want it to keep blinking after the full stop as well. Is there any way I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this works, but it works. Let me know if it gives the desired effect.

```
    .typewriter h2 {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'DM Mono', monospace;
        font-size: 40px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-right: .15em solid orange;
        //this is what i changed
        width: 12ch;
        animation: typing2 2s steps(12, end), blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
        ////
        animation-delay: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
    }
    @keyframes typing2 {
        from { 
            width: 0 
        }
        to {
            //this is what i changed
            width: 12ch;
            ////
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does'n work for me yet. Can't seem to have the cursor blinking at the end. The cursor is missing after the word 'This'

Comment: Try it now please.

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks a lot for helping out a newbie like me.